# How to open a project with AppCode from Xcode?

Tags: xcode, appcode

How to open a xcodeproj (or a xcworkspace) with AppCode from Xcode?

Without Finder.

Comment: Any reason you can't use Finder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can try [a plugin](https://github.com/orta/OROpenInAppCode) created by Orta Therox (developer of [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org))

Answer (score 1):

You can drag the Proxy icon (small xcodeproj icon at the top of the Xcode window). If AppCode supports drag-and-drop, you could try dragging that icon to the AppCode icon in the Dock.